# SGDClassifier Memory Issues

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn

I am using the `SGDClassifier` wrapped with the `OneVsRestClassifier` to do multi-label classification and I am running into memory issues.  Here is my code:

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', shuffle=True, alpha=0.000001, verbose=0, n_iter=5), n_jobs=1)
clf.fit(trainX, trainY)
```

`trainX` is a large ndarray - 6mil x 100 (float 64) = 5 GB ram.  There are approx 20,000 labels (so 20,000 linear classifiers are created) and my laptop has 16 GB of RAM.

I can load `trainX` and `trainY` with no problems, but when I start fitting the classifier, memory usage goes through the roof and very quickly my computer starts swapping and I have to kill the process.  I don't understand why fitting an `SGDClassifier` would cause that much extra memory usage because:

1) SGD feeds 1 sample through the algorithm at a time, so there should be minimal extra RAM usage.  If I can load the data, I should be able to train the classifier (which is whole point of SGD).

2) The coefficients of the SVM is large, but shouldn't cause a problem 20000x100

So what's causing the issue here?  Is the `OneVsRestClassifier` doing something that uses a lot of memory?  What can I do to get around this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: @larsmans Yeah this is a dupe.  Feel free to close.